# Android: Помощь c Adapter

Tags: android

Есть массив

```
public static Newsfeed parse(JSONObject root, boolean is_comments) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject response1 = root.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray jitems = response1.optJSONArray("items");
        JSONArray jprofiles = response1.optJSONArray("profiles");
        JSONArray jgroups = response1.optJSONArray("groups");
        Newsfeed newsfeed = new Newsfeed();
        if (jitems != null) {
            newsfeed.items = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
            for(int i = 0; i < jitems.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jitem = (JSONObject)jitems.get(i);
                NewsItem newsitem = NewsItem.parse(jitem, is_comments);
                newsfeed.items.add(newsitem);
    return newsfeed;
    ---------------
    public static NewsItem parse(JSONObject jitem, boolean is_comments) throws JSONException {
        NewsItem newsitem = new NewsItem();
        newsitem.type = jitem.getString("type");
        newsitem.source_id = Long.parseLong(jitem.getString("source_id"));
        String from_id=jitem.optString("from_id");
        if(from_id!=null && !from_id.equals(""))
            newsitem.from_id = Long.parseLong(from_id);
        newsitem.date = jitem.optLong("date");
        newsitem.post_id = jitem.optLong("post_id");
        newsitem.text = Api.unescape(jitem.optString("text"));
    return newsitem;
```

Мне надо "text" вот суда (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news)).setText(????????));
Что нужно туда вписать?

Comment: Просто совет: при десериализации JSON в класс используй GSON https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples весь твой код в 3-5 строк бы занял.

Answer (score 1):

Какой-то кривой вопрос, но из того что я понял получается:

```
String text = newsfeed.get(position).text;
(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news)).setText(text));
```